# Python Selenium pagination is not catched

Tags: python, selenium

I wrote a post this morning about getting all link of this page ["Credit Suisse"](https://tas-creditsuisse.taleo.net/careersection/campus/moresearch.ftl?lang=fr-FR).
I resolved my problem, but now, I want to click on the pagination url. The problem is that with the code below, I only get the job offer and I don't get the pagination links.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://tas-creditsuisse.taleo.net/careersection/campus/moresearch.ftl?lang=fr-FR")

webpage = ""
webpage = driver.page_source

import os
helloFile = open('C:\\Users\\Thie\\Desktop\\cs.html', 'w')
helloFile.write(webpage)
helloFile.close()

driver.close()
```

So, my question is how to get the pagination links and not only the job offers.
Do you have a way to do that ?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: do you need to click on the pagination link until the last page?

Comment: What do you mean by "get the pagination links?" Your question is unclear.

Comment: Yes, I need to click on the pagination link until the last page, but I can't find the pagination links.